# Run a stored procedure through MSSQL in Laravel 4.1 PHP, the procedure has a input and output

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Run a stored procedure through MSSQL in Laravel 4.1 PHP?**
The procedure has a input and output!

I am using Laravel 4.1
MSSQL 2012,

This is a example procedure that i created.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc @Input varchar(10), @Status int out
AS
BEGIN
set @Status = 0

select *
into #tmp
from test

select a.id, a.name, a.code
from test a
inner join #tmp b on a.id = b.id

drop table #tmp

set @Status = 1
END
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Run a stored procedure through MSSQL in Laravel PHP, the procedure has a input and output? What's the best way to do this...